# superset error - Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: apache-superset

I am setting up the superset on local system using this [image](https://github.com/transhapHigsn/apache-superset-bootstrap)

I am giving database connection by `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://username:password@localhost:5440/airflow'` in superset_config.py

I am using this command to run superset

```
docker run -it --rm --network host -v $(pwd):/app -e SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset_config.py -e FLASK_APP=superset superset-0.1 superset run -p 8088
```

When I login in superset, I am getting this error. Anybody know its solution?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the `user_attribute` table in your database and this is the cause of the error.